# How to estimate ARIMA models with MA and AR parts with specified lags

Tags: statistics, time-series, matlab, autoregressive-models

I am using Matlab 2013b and the econometrics toolbox to learn some ARIMA models.

When I want to specify AR lags in the ARIMA model as follows:

```
%Estimate simple ARMA model
model1 = arima('ARLags',[1 24],'MALags',0,'D',0);
EstMdl1 = estimate(model1,learningSet');
```

Then everything is fine when I estimate the model
If now I use

```
%Estimate simple ARMA model
model1 = arima('ARLags',[1 24],'MALags',1,'D',0);
EstMdl1 = estimate(model1,learningSet');
```

then the following error is issued:

```
Error using optimset (line 184)
Invalid value for OPTIONS parameter MaxNodes: must be a real non-negative integer.

Error in internal.econ.arma0 (line 195)
  options = optimset('lsqlin');

Error in arima/estimate (line 864)
  [AR0, MA0, constant, variance] = internal.econ.arma0(I(YData), LagOpAR0, LagOpMA0);
```

I am a bit puzzled about this and am looking for a workaround, if not an explanation of what is happening